# Could not find property 'run' on org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension_Decorated

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with Gradle.

Upgrading to the following:

```
 classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.RC1")
```

. . . from 1.2.7.RELEASE causes the following problem:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'vampr'.
> Could not find property 'run' on org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension_Decorated@12e13f2b.
```

How to fix this?

**Build file:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-1038'
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: "jacoco"


jar {
    baseName = 'vampr'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

// New entire sourceSets
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDir "src/main/kotlin"
        }
    }
    test {
        kotlin {
            srcDir "test/main/kotlin"
        }
    }
    integrationTest {
        kotlin {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/kotlin')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
//    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.mustRunAfter test

tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
}

test {
    jacoco {
        append = true
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}

jacoco {
    applyTo run
}

task applicationCodeCoverageReport(type:JacocoReport){
    executionData run
    sourceSets sourceSets.main
}
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Ah, good idea :P added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ver 1.3.0+ replaces the "run" attribute with "bootRun".

Try updating

```
jacoco {
    applyTo run
}
```

to

```
jacoco {
    applyTo bootRun
}
```

Comment: That was it - thanks. I was just getting back in to Java/Spring Boot when I asked that. Also needing to be changed was `task applicationCodeCoverageReport(type:JacocoReport)`